# Multiple rows of equations

Tags: equations

I'd like to know if there's a way of having multiple equations in one block of equation. Here's my first equation:

```
\begin{equation}
   \binom{n}{2} + 3 = \frac{1}{2} n^2 - 2
\end{equation}
```

Now I'd like to write every step of this problem. Is this possible without creating more equation blocks?

Comment: May be `align` environment?

Comment: I'd like the equations to be each in its own row and also numerated. Is that possible with align? I'm kinda new to LaTeX in general so I'm not sure.

Comment: The behavior you're describing is the default behavior for `align`.  The [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is an excellent read and should bring you up to speed quickly. `:-)` BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Look here for align, and you will get for sure results. Or look at [mathtools](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf) or [amsmath](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the document! I'll be sure to read it :) and also thanks for welcoming me here. Next year I'm starting college and I sure hope that I can use LaTeX for most of my stuff!

Comment: If you just need equations, use `gather`. If you want them to align nicely (at the `=` sign), then align is the way to go.

Comment: Yep! I managed to sort it out just like I wanted with align... Thanks again, guys!

Comment: Perhaps with the `amsmath' package you can do it easily. There are few environments that you can use, such as `align' or `gather' and you can use also starred versions if you want to avoid the number. Take a look at the documentation of the package, surelly you'll love it.